# Why is an error msg thrown when a function taking n parameters is passed to a sub function of a decorator function which contains 0 arguments

Tags: python, wrapper, decorator, python-decorators, word-wrap

I am new to python and trying to understand the languages functions and features.
When I run the below code, I get the error msg *"wrap() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given"*.

```
class dec:

def decorator_function(orig):
    def wrap():
        print('hi')
        return orig
    return wrap

@decorator_function
def display_inf(name, age):
    print('dispInf ran with args ({},{})'.format(name,age))

display_inf('John',35)
```

I understand what the error msg is and if I change the wrap function to include 2 parameters as below, I wouldn't get this msg. However what I don't get my head around is why python is throwing the error. The display_inf function is passed to the decorator_function as expected, however as far as the wrap function is concerned, all it does is printing *hi*. It's not even using the function so why am I still getting this error if I am not using it. What goes behind the scene that causes the error.

```
def decorator_function(orig):
    def wrap(name, age):
        print('hi')
        return orig
    return wrap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a decorator, your original function is *replaced* with the return value of the decorator.  In your example, `display_inf` is replaced with `wrap`.  Since `wrap` takes no arguments, when you try to call it with arguments, it fails.

You seem to be thinking that `wrap` will be called once and is supposed to return the new function, but that's not how it works.  The decorator itself (`decorator_functrion`) returns the new function, and in your case what it returns is `wrap`.  `wrap` never gets to actually print anything because it's called with the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: thank you for your detailed explanation. Now it all makes sense :-)